# Programming: principles and practice in c++ - cout issue

Tags: c++, cout

I started reading a well known book called **Programming: principles and practice in c++**. But the first program that was included in a book looked like that. Now, there are 2 problems. Line `#include "std_lib_facilities.h"` my compiler doesn't recognise as a valid code (I thought you should write include iostream) and down where the code cout is, wasn't there seposed to be a code named using namespace std; for the code cout to be written in short version.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h" 

int main()
{ 
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: this is from your book: [creating and running program](https://books.google.ca/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=programing:principles+and+practice&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=std_lib_facilities&f=false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should copy the header `std_lib_facilities.h` from the Stroustrup site. You can find the reference to the site in the book.

(Or look [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) )

Now you can just substitute this include for

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

Comment: A better practice is list the `std` items separately:  `using std::cout;`.  Thus not including the entire `std` namespace.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The derictives I showed are included in the header of Stroustrup.:)

Comment: Which is one more reason not to use it.  I get that he did it for the examples in the book to make them smaller but it runs against current coding practices.

Comment: But why would i have to do all that if you could just simpy write a code inlcude iostream. Also, is this book good for the beginners like me.

Comment: @ŽigaGazvoda This header will be required for other programs shown in the book.

Comment: The link that you provided me with. I copy all the text from here and then do what?

Comment: @ŽigaGazvoda You need to create a file (header) with this name and add it to the project.

Comment: Do you think this book is good for me as a beginer or would you recomend something else. Also it this thing with the header going to be explanied later on in the book?

Comment: @ŽigaGazvoda I am sure the book  is not good for beginners. I never advice this book for beginners.:)

Comment: Can u advice me something else. But as i have read a lot of people are recomending this book for beginners.

Comment: @ŽigaGazvoda A lot of people do not have their own brain.:) Unfortunately I can not advice a book on C++ because I do not read books on C++.:) Maybe you should read at first a book of Herbert Schildt or some other author.

Comment: @NathanOliver Looking at posts here I'd say it goes against coding *theory* but fully aligns with current coding *practice.* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Copy the header file from [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h). Save the file in the same directory as your code with the name `std_lib_facilities.h`. After that your code should compile.

As you can read from the file, `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` are already included so you don't have to write them again.

In C++, including header files is almost equivalent to copying everything from the header file and paste it to where the header is included.

Comment: But why would i have to do all that if you could just simpy write a code inlcude iostream. Also, is this book good for the beginners like me.

Comment: You could do that, but since you are following instructions from a book, the book might want you to use other things in the given header file.